# R: Sorting columns based on partial match of column names with row names

Tags: r

I have a data frame that can be simplified to look like this (included the dput at the end):

```
    T2_KL_21  A1_LC_11  W3_FA_22  RR_BI_12  PL_EW_12  RT_LC_22  YU_BI_21
FA  1         2         3         4         5         6         7
BI  1         2         3         4         5         6         7
KL  1         2         3         4         5         6         7
EW  1         2         3         4         5         6         7
LC  1         2         3         4         5         6         7
```

I would like to sort the columns so that they follow the order of the row names (based on partial match). It would then look like this:

```
    W3_FA_22  RR_BI_12  YU_BI_21  T2_KL_21  PL_EW_12  A1_LC_11  RT_LC_22
FA  3         4         7         1         5         2         6
BI  3         4         7         1         5         2         6
KL  3         4         7         1         5         2         6
EW  3         4         7         1         5         2         6
LC  3         4         7         1         5         2         6
```

If more than one column name contains the string in the row names, they should be kept side by side, but the order does not matter.

I have already filtered the columns so that they all contain a match in the row names.

Here is the dput of the data frame:

```
structure(list(T2_KL_21 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), A1_LC_11 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), W3_FA_22 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), RR_BI_12 = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), PL_EW_12 = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), RT_LC_22 = c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), YU_BI_21 = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("T2_KL_21", 
"A1_LC_11", "W3_FA_22", "RR_BI_12", "PL_EW_12", "RT_LC_22", "YU_BI_21"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("FA", "BI", "KL", "EW", 
"LC"))
```

I have tried using pmatch, grep and match, with no success.

Any advice will be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please make the changes you mentioned in the comments

Comment: I don't think that would change anything, what I meant was that row names could be for example F1A instead of FA, but that would also be true of the column names, so e.g. W3_F1A_22, that part would still match! Sorry if I caused any confusion

Comment: Ok, I updated the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can loop through the rownames and `grep` to find the index of the column names that match, `unlist` and use that to arrange the columns

```
df1[unlist(lapply(gsub("\\d+", "", row.names(df1)), function(x) grep(x, names(df1))))]
#W3_FA_22 RR_BI_12 YU_BI_21 T2_KL_21 PL_EW_12 A1_LC_11 RT_LC_22
#FA        3        4        7        1        5        2        6
#BI        3        4        7        1        5        2        6
#KL        3        4        7        1        5        2        6
#EW        3        4        7        1        5        2        6
#LC        3        4        7        1        5        2        6
```

Comment: This looks like it is partially working, it is only keeping one match per row, whereas there is more than one matching columns for two of the rows here (see example output table).

Comment: I should also add that it should work when the row names also contain numbers in addition to characters